# C# Removing trailing '\0' from IP Address string

Tags: c#, string, ip-address

I received a string over TCP socket. And this string looks something like this:

```
str = "10.100.200.200\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
```

How should I parse this into an IPAddress? If I do this,

```
IPAddress.TryParse(msg.nonTargetIP.Trim(), out ip);
```

it fails to parse.

What is simplest way to remove those trailing null's?

Comment: Is there ever a situation in which there would be data before the first '\' that you would need to hold on to?

Comment: Are the trailing characters literal backslashes or the null character?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
IPAddress.TryParse(msg.nonTargetIp.Replace("\0", String.Empty).Trim(), out ip);
```

Alternatively reading up on [Trim()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx#Y900) you could do the following which is probably quicker:

```
IPAddress.TryParse(msg.nonTargetIp.TrimEnd(new char[] { '\0' } ), out ip);
```

Answer (score 14):

The other examples have shown you how to trim the string - but it would be better not to get the "bad" data to start with.

My *guess* is that you have code like this:

```
// Bad code
byte[] data = new byte[8192];
stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

That's ignoring the return value of `Stream.Read`. Your code should be something like this instead:

```
// Better code
byte[] data = new byte[8192];
int bytesRead = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead);
```

Note that you should *also* check whether the stream has been closed, and don't assume you'll be able to read all the data in one call to `Read`, or that one call to `Write` at the other end corresponds to one call to `Read`.

Of course it's entirely possible that this isn't the case at all - but you should really check whether the other end is *trying* to send these extra "null" bytes at the end of the data. It sounds unlikely to me.

Comment: I am already using the "better code" version. But issue is that I working with the byte[] data and parsing that.

Comment: @ceonikka: Are you in control of the server? Is this garbage data expected?

Comment: I am the server and clients are mostly Java/C++ implementations.

Comment: @ceonikka: Okay, so what does the protocol say about what they *should* be sending you? How are you meant to know where the string ends?

Comment: Legacy Protocol says null terminated strings. On side note, I ran various trim/replace solutions under debugger and I don't seems to see any change in string. Though it works fine for IPAddress!!! Elsewhere may be I should just use split() method, to grab everything before '\0'??

Comment: Trim/Replace solutions definitely will work - but remember they won't change the existing string; they'll return a *new* string. I wouldn't use `Split` - I'd write one method to do this, which would use `IndexOf` to find the first `\0` and return everything before that.

Answer (score 5):

`str = str.Replace("\0","");` should work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

The Trim method is more efficient in comparison to the Replace method.

```
msg.nonTargetIP.Trim(new [] { '\0' });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try string replacement instead of trimming:

```
IPAddress.TryParse(msg.nonTargetIP.Replace("\0", ""), out ip);
```

Answer (score 1):

You **could** just use `TrimEnd()` for this:

```
bool isIPAddress = IPAddress.TryParse(msg.nonTargetIP.nonTargetIP.TrimEnd('\0'), out ip);
```

Note however that the example you give contains an illegal IP address and will never successfully parse regardless (300 is > 255, each decimal number must be in the range from 2 to 255).