# String.Trim() doesn't remove whitespaces

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, trim

I have a small program that loads or saves a byte array from or to a file. In this byte array is contained a string, for example:

```
byte[] header = new byte[64]; //the actual array is larger, but this is for explaining purposes only...
string savedString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString( header, 0, 64 );
```

because the string I used to write to the file was only 5 characters long, the "savedString" loads to be "string                                               " e.t.c.
However, in this situation, I had no worries, I just added

```
.Trim();
```

to

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString( header, 0, 64 );
```

yet this still doesn't cut the string down to the right size upon loading, so I'm guessing the padding is not made up of whitespaces?

Thanks.

Comment: are you assigning the `Trim()` result back to `savedString` ?

Comment: Is it *actually* text to start with? What's in this file, apart from the text data?

Comment: Look at the byte array and see what byte is in that position.

Comment: I'd guess that your string is being padded with null characters, not spaces.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683168/c-sharp-removing-trailing-0-from-ip-address-string

Comment: Show your code instead of snippets of a snippet. How are you using the `Trim()`?

Comment: Just so we're clear: `saveString = saveString.Trim()` right?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402622/string-from-byte-array-doesnt-get-trimmed-in-c?rq=1

Comment: I think no :) we are not Derek

Comment: Yes, savedString = savedString.Trim();

Comment: I've also tried printing the string to the console to see what it shows, but it just shows whitespaces, so surely it can't be just padded with 0s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The byte array is initially filled with zeros, and the the character that represents is a control character, and not a whitespace character. Try specifically trimming these zero-characters like this:

```
savedString.Trim('\0');
```

For example:

```
byte[] header = new byte[64];
header[0] = (byte)'A';
string savedString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(header, 0, 64);

var output1 = savedString.Trim();
Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", output1, output1.Length); // A□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□ (64)
var output2 = savedString.Trim('\0');
Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", output2, output2.Length); // A (1)
```